# OwinStartup stop firing with IIS ( but still working with IIS Express )

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have a Web API 2 application, hosted on IIS.

To configure OWIN, it has an startup class similar to this:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Application.Api
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            throw new Exception("Owin startup class fired"); // Added for test pourposes
        }
    }
}
```

The app was working like a charm until it stops firing the `Startup` class: no any change in the config file, no packages updates, the file **Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll** is present in the **bin** folder, the configuration is ok, etc.

Only it stops working, but if I set the project as **Startup Project** and run it with **F5** using **IIS Express** the startup class is loaded correctly.

I checked other posts with probably causes without luck:

- [OWIN not firing up if project not set as Startup with IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306461/owin-not-firing-up-if-project-not-set-as-startup-with-iis-express?rq=1)
- [OwinStartup not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203982/owinstartup-not-firing)
- [OwinStartup not Starting ... Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760545/owinstartup-not-starting-why?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Can't get the OWIN Startup class to run in IIS Express after renaming ASP.NET project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242581/cant-get-the-owin-startup-class-to-run-in-iis-express-after-renaming-asp-net-pr)

etc.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue using web.api 4.6.2, I followed the steps below and still encounter the issue. Any other pointers or advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with **TEMP files** of **ASP** and **IIS**.

So, to fix it, I followed the next steps:

1. From **Visual Studio**, **Build** => **Clean Solution**.
2. Close **Visual Studio**.
3. Delete all files from your project **bin** folder.
4. Delete all files from your project **obj** folder.
5. Remove **ASP.Net temp files**: on my installation, they are located into:
   `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root`
   and into:
   `C:\Users\[Your User]\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`.
6. Delete the **IIS temp files**. You can find the location opening your IIS Manager and selecting **.NET Compilation**:
   [image]
   Into **Assemblies** group you will see the setting **Temporary Directory**:
   [image]
   ( **G:\TEMP** in my installation )
7. **Remove** your API project site from **IIS**, and **add it again**.
8. Enter Visual Studio, **Build** => **Rebuild Solution**.
9. Test it.

I hope this help someone; I spent a lot of time with this nasty issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and searched and tried so many things. It turned out I had to **"Enable 32-bit Applications" in the application pool that my app on IIS was using.** 
Here's how:

On the Server you deployed your OWIN Application to...

1. Open IIS
2. Go to Application Pools
3. Right click on the application pool your OWIN app is using and click "advanced settings" (if you don't know what application pool your OWIN app is using, right click on your app -> "manage website" -> "advanced settings" -> "Application Pool" is the first item on list)
4. Set "Enable 32-bit Applications" to true
5. Restart app and if that was the problem, you app should now work.